# What factors exactly affect the speed, depth and range of scanning the mempool?

Tags: transactions, blocks, pending-transactions, txpool

There is zero quality information available on that topic anywhere, for obvious reasons. If there is however somebody willing to share, whether from experience or purely technical understanding of all the underlying technologies, would be more than open to hear about the details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.